# How I can distort image(movie clip) from rectangle to polar?

Tags: node-editor, image

How I can distort image(movie clip) from rectangle coords to polar? Maybe I can do it in Node Editor or whatever?
I need to replace pixels from XY to Angle R. But how I can do it? Thank you.

Comment: Please at least upload an image to show what the "polar" means to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a texture node to perform a uv distort on the image by applying the blend texture radial.
otherwise you would have to distort the real uv unwrap or possibly use a modifier to distort a mapped mesh in 3d view.

EDIT:
So I imported this plane into Blender as Add > Mesh > Images As Planes
Then add an empty and clear the location of both "alt G"
Select the image plane and add 2 modifiers.
1. Subsurf, use simple, increase divisions to 6
2. Add a simple Deform modifier set to Bend.
3. Set Origin as Empty, then enter Deform Angle as 360 deg.
4. alter empty location if required.
[image]